# UI Bootstrap datepicker - adding tooltip (ui bootstrap tooltip) for every day

Tags: datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I was trying to do that by adding an attribute of uib-tooltip to Datepicker, but after I saw the code I've seen that it isn't the proper way to do that...
Anyone have an idea for doing that?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: what have you tried ? can you post minimal viable example (some code that reproduces your problem) or a fiddle/plunker ? also why wasn't it "proper",?

Comment: this is the html code
<h4>Inline</h4>
    <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
      <uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" class="well well-sm" datepicker-options="options"></uib-datepicker>
    </div>

this is the $scope.options:
$scope.options = {
    customClass: getDayClass,
    minDate: new Date(),
    showWeeks: false,
    uibTooltip:"bla bla"
  };

Answer (score 1):

I've never done so myself but I think you could just override the default datepicker templates and just add a tooltip there

they can be found [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/template/datepicker).

then you can go to the [day view template](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/datepicker/day.html) and add a tooltip next to `ng-repeat="dt in row"`

```
<td ng-repeat="dt in row" uib-tooltip="hello tooltip"class="uib-day text-center" role="gridcell"
    id="{{::dt.uid}}"
    ng-class="::dt.customClass">
    <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"
      uib-is-class="
        'btn-info' for selectedDt,
        'active' for activeDt
        on dt"
      ng-click="select(dt.date)"
      ng-disabled="::dt.disabled"
      tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}">{{::dt.label}}</span></button>-->
</td>
```

If you are using the minified version of ui-bootstrap you're going to have to manipulate some of the component's source and minify it yourself

Comment: Thanks a lot!!
But, instead of overriding the original code, there is a way to chain the attribiute of uib-tooltip? I prefer this because in that way you can update the package of uib-datepicker more easily.

Comment: you can't "chain", you will have to add the tooltip to the exact markup of the day, so you will have to modify the template, but you don't actually need to override anything, datepicker has the `template-url` attribute where you can link (and override with) your own custom made templates.

Comment: It works!!
by the way, the uib-tooltip attribiute should be next to the button tag and not the <td> tag

Comment: well, i was just guessing, it looked like the best (and only) approach to solve it. :)